# Не срабатывает событие при нажатии на button

Tags: javascript

по задумке при нажатии на кнопку логин, div call_container должен менять свой display на block вместо none. но js не срабатывает, только начал изучать js, не понимаю, в чём проблема.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);

const callForm = document.querySelector('.call_container');
const open = document.getElementById('button_login');

function openForm () {
  callForm.style.display = 'block';
  alert('hey');
}

open.addEventListener('click', openForm);
```

```css
body {
  color: white;
}
.call_container {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #7586c4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: -260px;
  margin-left: 115px;
}
.call_container .call_form {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 35%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.call_container .call_form input {
  width: 100px;
  border: 0;
  background: white;
}
.call_container .call_form label {
  padding: 5px;
}
.call_container .call_form input[name="adress"] {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.call_container .call_form label[for="adress"] {
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.container {
  margin: 15% auto;
  height: 348px;
  width: 422px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px black;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(103, 145, 203, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)), radial-gradient(circle at -115px 2750px, #3f71b5 87%, transparent 87.1%), radial-gradient(circle at -292px 2000px, #305ea3 87%, transparent 87.1%), linear-gradient(4deg, #3f71b5 73%, #305ea3 74%);
}
.container .wrapper {
  padding: 46px 28px 29px 45px;
}
.container .wrapper .login {
  font-family: "TimesNewRoman", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2.3em;
}
.container .wrapper .lorem {
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.container .wrapper form {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.container .wrapper form input {
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 204px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background: #1e4f8a;
  border: 1px solid #002043;
  color: white;
}
.container .wrapper form label {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}
.container .wrapper form label[for="email"] {
  margin-left: 23px;
}
.container .wrapper form label[for="check_box"] {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -97px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  font-size: 0.7em;
}
.container .wrapper form input[type="password"] {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.container .wrapper form input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin-left: -27px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.container .wrapper form ::placeholder {
  color: white;
}
.container .wrapper form a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  margin-left: 30px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.container .wrapper form button {
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 69px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: #4684d1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font-family: "TimesNewRoman", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <span class="login">Login</span>
      <br>
      <span class="lorem">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</span>
      <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email..." value="">
        <br>
        <label for="pass">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="••••••••" value="">
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check_box" value="">
        <label for="check_box">Remember Me</label>
        <a href="#">Forgot password?</a>
        <button type="button" id="button_login" name="button">LOGIN</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="call_container">
      <div class="call_form">
        <label for="phone">Ваш номер</label>
        <input type="number" name="phone" value="">
        <label for="adress">Ваш адрес</label>
        <input type="text" name="adress" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите строку `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready);` и ваш код заработает (если скрипт находится в конце страницы). Сейчас он падает с ошибкой, т.к. обработчик `ready` не определён.

Либо можно определить `ready`:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready);

function ready() {
  const callForm = document.querySelector('.call_container');
  const open = document.getElementById('button_login');

  function openForm() {
    console.log('111');
    callForm.style.display = 'block';
    alert('hey');
  }

  open.addEventListener('click', openForm);
}
```

Comment: то есть событие DOMContentLoaded не стоит постоянно использовать? во многих справочниках/учебниках кратко написано, что это нужно прописывать, чтобы дождаться загрузки html

Comment: @СотниЛичностей обновил ответ с использованием DOMContentLoaded ✌️